# Right approach using git merge

Tags: git

I have an repository. Someone of my teammates merged an branch with `dev` branch. My branch is behind of the last merge of my teammate. How is correct, to pull changes from `dev` in my branch and to fix the conflicts if they exist, or to merge my branch with `dev` and to fix the conflicts in process of merging?

Comment: What have you tried so far? (I ask because "best practice" questions are too open and tend to gain opionated answers)

Comment: @evolutionxbox, i tried the both situations, but which is correct? I know that, traditionally  all conflicts all solved in the process of merging, but i want to know if also is correct  to pull the changes from 'dev', to solve the conflicts, and only after that to merge with `dev`?

Comment: The answer is likely to be 'it depends'. A common solution is to rebase your local branch onto the updated `dev` branch, but don't do that if you've already shared your branch. Another common solution is to update `dev` and then merge it into your branch, and push.

Answer (score 0):

- If you have not published your `topic` branch yet, you may rebase it onto `dev` to spare a merge commit, or if you merge into the long-running branch with `--no-ff`, preserve first-parent history.
- Otherwise, if you can push to `dev`, merge `topic` into `dev` to preserve first-parent history.
- Else merge `dev` into `topic`.

If you have already merged your `topic` branch into `dev` locally, but the push is rejected, do `git pull --rebase` on `dev`.

Comment: could you please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71657393/git-add-a-usage and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71658921/git-add-only-modified-files