# Git add -A usage

Tags: reactjs, git

I am using `Husky` in my ReactJs project. The idea is when user will commit the changes there should be run some lint commands.For this i added in my `package.json`:

```js
    "lint": "next lint --fix",
    "lint:fix": "lint && git add -A .",
```

Before committing the message i run `lint:fix`. Everything is working. 
Also i know that this command `git add -A .` will add the changes if they will occur after `lint` command, so if the dev will commit => `lint` will fix the issues => and if there are some changes git automatically will add these changes to the commit without doing again `git add .` and `git commit -m ...`.
 Question: Have this  command `git add -A .` any disadvantages and is it ok to add there?

Comment: In general, you *should not* run `git add` in any pre-commit hooks. You *should* test what the *user* has provided as "I intend to commit these versions", and if the test fails, prohibit the commit while saying why you're prohibiting the commit. Leave it to the user to run any sort of "automatically fix up my files" operation: the pre-commit hook is just a *verifier*, not a *repairer*.

Answer (score 4):

> Have this command git add -A . any disadvantages

First `git add .` is enough (the [`-A` is the default since Git 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66115398/6309))

Second, the main (in general) inconvenient is that it adds everything, even if you might have other unrelated modifications. It also adds new files.

In your case (used in a pre-commit hook), you have prepared your index (`git add` only the files you want to commit): the `git add .` might risk adding *other* files that you did not want initially to iclude in your next commit.

---

> another question, is `lint-staged` (https://npmjs.com/package/lint-staged) the same as `git add -u` in my situation "`lint:fix`": "`lint && git add -u`"?

The [README mentions](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#v10=):

> From v10.0.0 onwards any new modifications to originally staged files will be automatically added to the commit.
>
> **If your task previously contained a `git add` step, please remove this**.
>
> The automatic behaviour ensures there are less race-conditions, since trying to run multiple `git` operations at the same time usually results in an error.

Comment: It is unclear. How can i have `other unrelated modifications. It also adds new files.` ? I think that all modification are related to the commit, because whenyou run commit it will fix all lint/prettier issues and after that using `git add  -A.` aill add all of them to the commit. Coould you explain how could appear others `unrelated modifications`?

Comment: @Asking Do you run that as part of a pre-commit hook?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: @Asking OK. I have edited my answer.

Comment: could you please give me an example how can appear `other files that i did not want initially to include in the commit`? Because i understand next: 1. Dev commit 2. then `lint:fix` runs 3. It fixes the lint/prettier issues and due of `git add -A .` will add at once all the changes (eslint/prettier) fixes to my commit that was created before. Am i right?

Comment: @Asking a git add will not add all the the changes (eslint/prettier). It will add any modified/deleted/added files, not just the ones changed by eslint/prettier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243402/discussion-between-asking-and-vonc).

Comment: could you please access the chat? I am there.

Comment: am i right if adding `"lint:fix": "lint && git add -u"` will be better? And in this way it will add only the files that was affected by my changes. And also, i think that i understood your point related `-A .`, if i will do some changes in file `X` and after that will commit and the `lint:fix` will run and will create changes in X, Y and A files, then because of `-A .` all changes will be committed, but with `git add -u` i will add  to commit only the changes from `X` file. Please correct me if i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: @Asking I am in the chat.

Comment: also another question, is lint-staged https://www.npmjs.com/package/lint-staged the same as `git add -u` in my situation "lint:fix": "lint && git add -u"?